# Собрал kivy приложение в apk. Но на android не работает

Tags: android, python, kivy

Собрал через buildozer. На linux все прекрасно работает и с apk устанавливается. Но на android запускается потом сразу же вылетает. Можете сказать что в коде неправильно. Думаю дело в коде илиже Я неправильно собрал. Просто kivylauncher не открывает тоже. Пожалуйста помогите.
main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as C
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, FadeTransition, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import sqlite3
__version__ = '0.1'
kivy.require('1.9.1')

class UI(FloatLayout):
    pass
class BaseScreen(Screen):

    td_list_view = ObjectProperty()
    def update(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT do FROM tasks')
        while True:
            row = []
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                break
            for task in row:
                task = str(task)
                self.td_list_view.adapter.data.extend([task])
                self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    def task_done(self):
        if self.td_list_view.adapter.selection:
            selection = self.td_list_view.adapter.selection[0].text
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
            print(selection)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE do == ("%s")'%selection)
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            self.td_list_view.adapter.data.remove(selection)
            self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()



class AddTaskScreen(Screen):
    bs = BaseScreen
    text_input = ObjectProperty()

    def add_task(self, temp):
       # with open(file, 'w') as fileObject:
        #    fileObject.write(self.text_input.text+"\n")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tasks (do) VALUES ("%s")'%(temp))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        self.bs.update


class ToDoListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass

Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class TodoApp(App):
    title = "To do"

    def update_task(self):
        self.base_screen.td_list_view.adapter.data.extend([self.task.text_input.text])
        self.base_screen.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()

    def on_start(self):
        self.base_screen.update()

    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.base_screen = BaseScreen(name="base")
        self.task = AddTaskScreen(name='task')
        self.sm.add_widget(self.base_screen)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.task)
        return self.sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TodoApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import main main
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import TextInput kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput

<BaseScreen>:
    td_list_view: list_view
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#ff777b')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            pos: 0, 450
            Label:
                text: "Tasks"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos: 0, 130
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 310
            ListView:
                id: list_view
                adapter:
                    ListAdapter(data = [""], cls=main.ToDoListButton)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            pos: 86, 15
            spacing: 15

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_normal: "plus.png"
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = 'task'

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_normal: "done.png"
                on_press: root.task_done()


<AddTaskScreen>:
    text_input: text_input
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#ff777b')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            pos: 0, 450
            Label:
                text: "Tasks"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos: 0, 350
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            TextInput:
                id: text_input
                text: "Add your Task"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 288
                focus: True
                readonly: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 15
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            pos: 69, 15

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_color: C("#f06d73")
                background_normal: "go-back.png"
                color: C("#ffffff")
                font_size: 15
                bold: True
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = 'base'

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 75, 75
                background_color: C("#f06d73")
                background_normal: ""
                text: "Add Task"
                color: C("#ffffff")
                font_size: 15
                bold: True
                on_press: root.add_task(text_input.text)
                on_press: app.update_task()
```

buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = To Do List

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapptododdd

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.testtoss

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
#version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = sqlite3,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Answer (score -1):

Логи смотри. Каждый проект Kivy содержит папку .kivy, в которой есть директория logs. Там информация о последнем запуске приложения. В Бульдозере укажи `android.private_storage = false` Тогда папка с проектом будет установлена на sdcard, а не в `root/data/data` и ты сможешь посмотреть ошибку.

И стандартные виджеты Kivy не нужно импортировать в kv файлах.

Comment: Хорошо попробую

Comment: Извините но я не могу найти .kivy. И еще sdcard папку с проектом это в телефоне надо искать.

Comment: Вот ошибка в логах можете помочь что не так.

Comment: вот ссылка на новый вопрос помогите прошу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847698/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-kivy-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-apk-%d0%9d%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-warning-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80