# Ошибки Warning при компиляции kivy проекта в apk

Tags: android, python, kivy, apk

Хочу скомпилировать kivy проект в apk. Но выходит ошибки Warning. Помогите разобраться.

Это ошибка:

> ```
> [INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /home/kaze/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-06-28_1.txt
> [INFO   ] Kivy: v1.11.0.dev0, git-Unknown, 20180625
> [INFO   ] Python: v3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
> [GCC 7.3.0]
> [INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
> [INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif 
>           (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
> [INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
> [INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
> [INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
> [INFO   ] GL: Backend used <gl>
> [INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5'>
> [INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'nouveau'>
> [INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'NVE7'>
> [INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
> [INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'1.30'>
> [INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <16384>
> [INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <32>
> [INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
> [INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
> [WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           uix/listview.py line 845.Called from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           lang/builder.py line 582 by _apply_rule().
> [WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           adapters/simplelistadapter.py line 49.Called from /usr/lib/python3/
>           dist-packages/kivy/uix/listview.py line 859 by __init__().
> [WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           adapters/adapter.py line 111.Called from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
>           kivy/adapters/simplelistadapter.py line 55 by __init__().
> [WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           uix/abstractview.py line 42.Called from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           uix/listview.py line 865 by __init__().
> [WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           adapters/listadapter.py line 185.Called from /home/kaze/test2/main.kv 
>           line 32 by <module>().
> [WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/
>           adapters/adapter.py line 111.Called from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
>           kivy/adapters/listadapter.py line 186 by __init__().
> [INFO   ] Clipboard: Provider: xclip
> [INFO   ] CutBuffer: cut buffer support enabled
> [INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
> [INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event6
> [INFO   ] MTD: Read event from </dev/input/event6>
> [INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
> [WARNING] MTD: Unable to open device "/dev/input/event6". Please ensure you have the 
>           appropriate permissions.
> [WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
>           kivy/uix/selectableview.py line 38. Called from /usr/lib/python3/
>           dist-packages/kivy/uix/listview.py line 593 by __init__().
> ```

Код main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as C
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import sqlite3
__version__ = '0.1'
kivy.require('1.9.1')
Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class BaseScreen(Screen):

    td_list_view = ObjectProperty()
    def update(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT do FROM tasks')
        while True:
            row = []
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                break
            for task in row:
                task = str(task)
                self.td_list_view.adapter.data.extend([task])
                self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    def task_done(self):
        if self.td_list_view.adapter.selection:
            selection = self.td_list_view.adapter.selection[0].text
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
            print(selection)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE do == ("%s")'%selection)
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            self.td_list_view.adapter.data.remove(selection)
            self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()



class AddTaskScreen(Screen):
    bs = BaseScreen
    text_input = ObjectProperty()

    def add_task(self, temp):
       # with open(file, 'w') as fileObject:
        #    fileObject.write(self.text_input.text+"\n")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tasks (do) VALUES ("%s")'%(temp))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        self.bs.update


class ToDoListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass



class TodoApp(App):
    title = "To do"

    def update_task(self):
        self.base_screen.td_list_view.adapter.data.extend([self.task.text_input.text])
        self.base_screen.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()

    def on_start(self):
        self.base_screen.update()

    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.base_screen = BaseScreen(name="base")
        self.task = AddTaskScreen(name='task')
        self.sm.add_widget(self.base_screen)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.task)
        return self.sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TodoApp().run()
```

Код main.kv:

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import main main

<BaseScreen>:
    td_list_view: list_view
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#ff777b')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            pos: 0, 450
            Label:
                text: "Tasks"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos: 0, 130
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 310
            ListView:
                id: list_view
                adapter:
                    ListAdapter(data = [""], cls=main.ToDoListButton)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            pos: 86, 15
            spacing: 15

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_normal: "plus.png"
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = 'task'

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_normal: "done.png"
                on_press: root.task_done()


<AddTaskScreen>:
    text_input: text_input
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#ff777b')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            pos: 0, 450
            Label:
                text: "Tasks"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos: 0, 350
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            TextInput:
                id: text_input
                text: "Add your Task"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 288
                focus: True
                readonly: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 15
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            pos: 69, 15

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_color: C("#f06d73")
                background_normal: "go-back.png"
                color: C("#ffffff")
                font_size: 15
                bold: True
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = 'base'

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 75, 75
                background_color: C("#f06d73")
                background_normal: ""
                text: "Add Task"
                color: C("#ffffff")
                font_size: 15
                bold: True
                on_press: root.add_task(text_input.text)
                on_press: app.update_task()
```

Comment: Warning - это не ошибки, а предупреждения. Предупреждают они вас о том, что в 32-й строке main.kv вы используете ListAdapter устаревшим способом.

Comment: Если так то как я могу скомпилировать так чтобы. Приложение на android запустилось и не вылетала.

Comment: Оно устанавливается но вылетает.

Comment: Если вылетает после запуска, то это ошибка не сборки, а времени выполнения. Берите [logcat](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) и анализируйте логи.

Comment: Утром вам отвечу, сейчас не могу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Собрал kivy приложение в apk. Но на android не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847156/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb-kivy-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-apk-%d0%9d%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: мне кажется проблема именно в этом.. хоть и Warning "MTD: Unable to open device "/dev/input/event6". Please ensure you have the 
          appropriate permissions."